# google sheet formula : vlookup across multiple columns not working

Tags: google-sheets

this is my [spreadsheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1XCnUPxQjGZG2NVoqLM0sC34IYixXPNVwy1DRUUqk4Xo/edit?usp=sharing)

on first sheet 'consolidation' column O

I want to get the date value by

finding the number from 'articles' sheet [column H to AJ] [articles!H:AJ]

that match with the value in column M of 'consolidation'

then return the date from column F [articles!F:F]

[image]

so on cell O6 I put in this formula

> =VLOOKUP(M6,articles!F:AJ,{1},0)

{1} is column F that I want to return

[it has multiple results but I think vlookup will return the first one that it found which is fine cause it sorted by date]

but the problem is it's not finding anything on 'articles' range F:AJ

I don't know why

this might be the stupid way to do

anyone know please give me an advice, thanks

Comment: there's nothing hide in 'articles' - there's no 1 but there should be another number in another row - pls test in O13 - thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(TEXTJOIN(",",1,IF(REGEXMATCH(","&articles!B:B,","&M6&","),TEXT(articles!F:F,"mm/dd/yyyy"),)))
```

- REGEX to match M6 to anything between the `,`
- IF to find the date
- JOIN to join the found dates

Comment: then I got FALSE,FALSE,.. by the way I found another formula that might do the same thing =(MAX(filter(articles!F:F,regexmatch(","&articles!B:B,","&M6&",")))) -but seems like it will get any field that contains that number .for example,if we wanna find 1 it will get the field that has 0,11,.. as well

Comment: appreciate your help - now it has the date format but the result not correct - you can check on column N (number of news item) if it's 0 then it should find nothing - you can edit everything on the sheet to test - it's a copy of the real one

Comment: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1XCnUPxQjGZG2NVoqLM0sC34IYixXPNVwy1DRUUqk4Xo/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: thanks a lot!! I was confused with the date format. now it works like a charm ! thank you thank you thank you

Comment: one more question, if I wanna get the max date,where should I put the max in the formula?